# Minikube suddenly stopped working after wireless network restarted?

Tags: minikube

I created a cluster with minikube using driver `none`. The reason for this was that I could not get Nvidia GPU support running with `kvm2` driver. And documentation mentions driver `none` as alternative.
However, Minikube worked nicely, and after that I installed Kubeflow. I checked GPU availability with a JupyterLab notebook with a PyTorch GPU kernel. The notebook got a CUDA device. So far so good.
During the night the wireless router collapsed and was back up in the morning.
I dont know if this is a coincidence, but Minikube is not working anymore. At least the IP address on the wifi interface did not change.
I restarted Minikube, it comes up with

```
chris@laptop1:~$ minikube start --driver=none --apiserver-ips 127.0.0.1 --apiserver-name localhost
  minikube v1.31.2 on Linuxmint 5
✨  Using the none driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Restarting existing none bare metal machine for "minikube" ...
ℹ️  OS release is LMDE 5 (elsie)
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.27.4 on Docker 24.0.5 ...
  Configuring bridge CNI (Container Networking Interface) ...
  Configuring local host environment ...

❗  The 'none' driver is designed for experts who need to integrate with an existing VM
  Most users should use the newer 'docker' driver instead, which does not require root!
  For more information, see: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/

❗  kubectl and minikube configuration will be stored in /home/chris
❗  To use kubectl or minikube commands as your own user, you may need to relocate them. For example, to overwrite your own settings, run:

    ▪ sudo mv /home/chris/.kube /home/chris/.minikube $HOME
    ▪ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube $HOME/.minikube

  This can also be done automatically by setting the env var CHANGE_MINIKUBE_NONE_USER=true
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
    ▪ Using image registry.k8s.io/nvidia-gpu-device-plugin
    ▪ Using image registry.k8s.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.4
    ▪ Using image docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.7.0
    ▪ Using image docker.io/kubernetesui/metrics-scraper:v1.0.8
  Some dashboard features require the metrics-server addon. To enable all features please run:

    minikube addons enable metrics-server   


  Enabled addons: default-storageclass, nvidia-gpu-device-plugin, storage-provisioner, dashboard, metrics-server
  kubectl not found. If you need it, try: 'minikube kubectl -- get pods -A'
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
Side note: metrics-server addon is already enabled, but Minikube is complaining every time about it.
```

Looking at Minikubes status:

```
chris@laptop1:~$ minikube status
[sudo] password for chris:            
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

I tried `update-context`:

```
chris@laptop1:~$ minikube update-context
[sudo] password for chris:            
  No changes required for the "minikube" context
  Current context is "minikube"
```

The status of the pods of Minikube are:

```
Every 5.0s: minikube kubectl -- get pods -A

NAMESPACE                   NAME                                                    READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS          AGE
auth                        dex-c869557db-wm7zj                                     1/1     Running                      17 (66m ago)      37h
cert-manager                cert-manager-66d9545484-vx5ds                           1/1     Running                      17 (66m ago)      37h
cert-manager                cert-manager-cainjector-7d8b6bd6fb-b4qs2                1/1     Running                      61 (66m ago)      37h
cert-manager                cert-manager-webhook-669b96dcfd-mrd5q                   1/1     Running                      18 (66m ago)      37h
istio-system                authservice-0                                           0/1     Running                      10 (66m ago)      19h
istio-system                cluster-local-gateway-5d9df8bb5f-kvxrf                  0/1     Running                      14 (65m ago)      37h
istio-system                istio-ingressgateway-79f4d978bb-r627l                   0/1     Running                      14 (65m ago)      37h
istio-system                istiod-8687b6c5dc-5h4rx                                 1/1     Running                      14 (66m ago)      37h
knative-eventing            eventing-controller-97d775599-z4hh4                     1/1     Running                      15 (66m ago)      37h
knative-eventing            eventing-webhook-65674c956f-c7kb5                       1/1     Running                      16 (65m ago)      37h
knative-serving             activator-695675979-d9rfr                               0/2     CrashLoopBackOff             107 (3m28s ago)   37h
knative-serving             autoscaler-5dd8cbff77-sp2jl                             0/2     CrashLoopBackOff             116 (4m49s ago)   37h
knative-serving             controller-d96965c45-qqgf7                              0/2     CrashLoopBackOff             120 (39s ago)     37h
knative-serving             domain-mapping-d74c78c76-cx6rr                          0/2     CrashLoopBackOff             116 (58s ago)     37h
knative-serving             domainmapping-webhook-6b5d885fdd-9xbp9                  0/2     CrashLoopBackOff             114 (44s ago)     37h
knative-serving             net-istio-controller-5c4cdf4f58-ndzpr                   0/2     CrashLoopBackOff             118 (59s ago)     37h
knative-serving             net-istio-webhook-846b6447b8-85xhg                      0/2     CrashLoopBackOff             112 (51s ago)     37h
knative-serving             webhook-6dff9767d7-5dmvb                                0/2     CrashLoopBackOff             115 (71s ago)     37h
kube-system                 coredns-5d78c9869d-zbcrz                                1/1     Running                      14 (65m ago)      36h
kube-system                 etcd-laptop1                                            1/1     Running                      4 (66m ago)       4h12m
kube-system                 kube-apiserver-laptop1                                  1/1     Running                      4 (65m ago)       4h12m
kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-laptop1                         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff             67 (10s ago)      37h
kube-system                 kube-proxy-kfjzg                                        1/1     Running                      14 (66m ago)      37h
kube-system                 kube-scheduler-laptop1                                  1/1     Running                      14 (66m ago)      37h
kube-system                 nvidia-gpu-device-plugin-m5cpk                          1/1     Running                      14 (66m ago)      37h
kube-system                 storage-provisioner                                     1/1     Running                      66 (66m ago)      37h
```

Checking the logs of the pods which are in state `CrashLoopBackOff` tells me that they are unhealthy (e.g. knative-serving net-istio-controller-5c4cdf4f58-ndzpr):

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  2m25s (x2478 over 72m)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.244.2.255:15021/healthz/ready": dial tcp 10.244.2.255:15021: connect: connection refused
```

I checked the logs of the apiserver:

```
chris@laptop1:~$ minikube kubectl -- logs -n kube-system kube-apiserver-laptop1
...
W0826 11:39:28.518261       1 dispatcher.go:197] Failed calling webhook, failing open config.webhook.eventing.knative.dev: failed calling webhook "config.webhook.eventing.knative.dev": failed to call webhook: Post "https://eventing-webho>
E0826 11:39:28.518353       1 dispatcher.go:204] failed calling webhook "config.webhook.eventing.knative.dev": failed to call webhook: Post "https://eventing-webhook.knative-eventing.svc:443/config-validation?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.10>
...
```

In Minikube status I can see lots of the following:

```
E0826 10:19:05.671399       1 reflector.go:148] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.ReplicaSet: failed to list *v1.ReplicaSet: Get "https://192.168.0.150:8443/apis/apps/v1/replicasets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, 192.168.43.66, 10.96.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.1, not 192.168.0.150
...
E0826 10:19:25.390830       1 run.go:74] "command failed" err="finished without leader elect"
I0826 10:19:25.390842       1 tlsconfig.go:255] "Shutting down DynamicServingCertificateController"
```

`192.168.0.150` is the IP address on the wifi interface. Thats an IP address which might change constantly, depending on where and how I connect the laptop to a network.

How can I fix this issue (if it is the cause of Minukube not working anymore)?
Might it be possible that Minikube uses `127.0.0.1` IP address instead of a changing one of DHCP managed network interfaces?

UPDATE: Just oin case anybody comes across the same issue:
I fixed the issue with adding the IP address to `--apiserver-ips`

```
minikube start --driver=none --apiserver-ips 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.150 --apiserver-name localhost
```